# Get-ADUser via Scheduled Task on PCs Not Working

Tags: powershell

I have a task set up via GPO that is running a PowerShell script. I have found out that Get-ADUser can only be used if the module is available on the machine you are running the script on. Is there another way of seeing if a user is in a specific group when running on several client machines that I do not want to install anything extra on? This was easy with VBScript, but I'm not sure how else to do it with PowerShell. Here is the one line that is not working on machines without AD:

```
If ((Get-ADUser $User -Properties memberof).memberof -like "CN=GROUP*")
```

With VBScript, the following works on all machines:

```
If IsMember("GROUP") Then
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the DistinguishedName(See Function Above) of the user, and your DomainController name, then you can use [ADSI] type without the active directory module, like this:

**DC** = Name of your DomainController //**DC**/$UserDN

```
Function Get-DN ($SAMName)
{

      $root = [ADSI]''
      $searcher = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($root)
      $searcher.filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName= $SAMName))"
      $user = $searcher.findall()

if ($user.count -gt 1)
      {     
      $count = 0

      foreach($i in $user)
      {
      write-host $count ": " $i.path 
      $count = $count + 1
      }

      $selection = Read-Host "Please select item: "

Return $user[$selection].path

      }
      else
      {
      return $user[0].path
      }

}

$GroupName = "MyGroup"
$UserDN = Get-DN $env:USERNAME
$user = [adsi]$UserDN 

if ($User.memberOf -match $GroupName)
{
"The User is Member of $GroupName"
}

else
{
"The User is not Member of $GroupName"
}
```